# Downloading matrix32.dll file

Tags: dll

I want to run some application and I get this error:
"The dynamic link library 'matrix32.dll' could not be found."

Mostly when I have problem with dll files, I search and download dll file.

But when I searched for matrix32.dll I couldn't find the exact dll file. There are a lot of dll fixer applications which doesn't work properly and also I don't trust them.

What is wrong with this dll file? 
What is exactly for?
Is it about security or something like that?
Do you know any site which provides exact file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A [quick search](http://systemexplorer.net/file-database/file/matrix32-dll) shows me this is part of a security package made by [TDi GmbH TechnoData - Interware](http://www.tdi-matrix.com/english/). If you need this to run your software, it should be part of the original installation program. Just run it again (repair if possible, reinstall if not).

Comment: I tried to install program couple times but I still get this error.